# How to get value of con[]=2?

Tags: php

```
Array ( [keyword] => [location] => [values] => con[]=1&con[]=2&con[]=3&con[]=4 )
```

In this arry I want to get value of **con[]=2**

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are asking.  Not my downvote !

Comment: I want to get value 2 which is on index of values @ Rohit Gupta

Comment: Are this values from $_GET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use $_POST then u can get

```
 preg_match_all('!\d+!', $_POST['values'], $matches);
 $data = $matches[0];
 echo $data[2];
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP has a built-in [parse_str()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) function that should allow you to extract this to an array

```
parse_str($myOriginalArray['values'], $output);
var_dump($output['con']);
```